# Programmatically writing a div in a template

Tags: meteor

I want to change a `div` in a template programatically but I can't get it to work.  Is there a way to do this using a helper function?

```
   Template.home.helpers({
         jcropdiv: function() {
               var div = '';
               if(Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.user(), ['admin'])){
                 div = '<div id="jcrop_target">';
               } else {
                 div = '<div class="jcrop-holder" style="background-color: black; height: 719px; width: 1280px; position: relative;">';
               } 
               return div;
         }
   });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up with:

```
//template
 <div id="{{jcropdiv.id}}" class="{{jcropdiv.class}}" style="{{jcropdiv.style}}">


//js
Template.home.helpers({
     jcropdiv: function() {
           var tags={};
           if(Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.user(), ['Sponsor'])){
            tags.id = 'jcrop_target';
           } else {
              tags.class = 'jcrop-holder';
              tags.style = 'background-color: black; height: 719px; width: 1280px; position: relative;';
           } 
           return tags;
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe you can write tags dynamically, but you ***CAN*** add attributes to a tag dynamically.  For example:

```
<div {{jcropdiv}}>
  Stuff
</div>

Template.home.helpers({
         jcropdiv: function() {
               var tags;
               if(Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.user(), ['admin'])){
                 tags = 'id="jcrop_target"';
               } else {
                 tags = 'class="jcrop-holder" style="background-color: black; height: 719px; width: 1280px; position: relative;"';
               } 
               return tags;
         }
   });
```

That should return either `id="jcrop_target"` or `'class="jcrop-holder" style="background-color: black; height: 719px; width: 1280px; position: relative;"'` based on if the user is in the 'admin' role.

Comment: I tried that earlier and it didn't work.  Tried your code just incase I missed something, got the same error:  Exception from Tracker recompute function:
meteor....a1802d4 (line 880)
InvalidCharacterError: String contains an invalid character

Comment: You may need to do each one individually.  I know I have used this to return which class needs to be added to an element, and I have definitely used it to set the `disabled` attribute.

Comment: Thanks for the extra advice.  It could be because some of the packages I'm using need updated, I'm using version 1.2.1 of Meteor at the moment.

Comment: I was using dynamic class values and such in 1.2, and even back in 1.1.  I don't have access to any meteor code at the moment, but I am absolutely certain it will work.  I would suggest starting simple/small.  See if you can just dynamically set the class.  Return either `jcrop-holder` or undefined.  If that works, see if you can return `class="jcrop-holder"`, and so on.

Comment: I tried, it appears its the quotes that it doesn't like.  I've got a work around anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do something like this in your temaplate instead of making helper

```
{{#if isInRole 'admin'}}
  <div id="jcrop_target">
    //do something
  </div>
{{else}}
  <div class="jcrop-holder" style="background-color: black; height: 719px; width: 1280px; position: relative;">
   //do something else
  </div>
{{/if}}
```

I believe it helps

Thanks

Comment: There's just too much stuff in between the div tags and it would start to get messy.